# Flir Blackfly BFLY-PGE-31S4C (Power of Ethernet) not working with autoware?[SOLVED]

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ubuntu, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need a technical support about how to connect to a Gige camera to our Astuff Spectra.

Currently my working environment are:
Device: Astuff Spectra
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Platform: Autoware.ai + ROS 1
Camera: Flir Blackfly BFLY-PGE-31S4C (Power of Ethernet)
What I did was:
The camera was connected to a PoE switch, PoE switch was connected to Astuff Spectra.
Downloaded and built a point-grey-driver node (I am not sure this is correct driver for this camera)
https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver
Downloaded and installed Spinnaker SDK (spinnaker-2.2.0.48-Ubuntu18.04-arm64-pkg.tar.gz)
https://meta.box.lenovo.com/v/link/view/a1995795ffba47dbbe45771477319cc3
Downloaded and installed FlyCapture2 SDK (flycapture2-2.13.3.31_Ubuntu18.04-amd64-pkg.tgz)
I executed the following command, but it shows that there was no camera be detected
rosrun pointgrey_camera_driver list_cameras
Then I opened flyCap GUI and click "Auto force IP", same thing there was not camera be detected.
Final, I connected the camera to my Windows10 PC. The camera can be detected, and you can see some information like, camera serial number was 20268394, IP Address was 169.254.69.106, etc.

That means the camera device was good, but it can not be detected by Linux.
Did I install a correct driver for this camera? or should I configure some other files?
It would be nice if anyone can help me with this, If you need more information just let me know.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364711/flir-blackfly-bfly-pge-31s4c-(power-of-ethernet)-not-working-with-autoware?%5Bsolved%5D/) by [sudip](https://answers.ros.org/users/55839/sudip/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-11-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-11-10**:
I highly recommend you contact AutonomouStuff support for this issue. This is related to the camera and the Blackfly SDK rather than Autoware or ROS and they will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason was due to firewall. We have to disable firewall and the camera works perfectly. Thank you for the reply Josh! Appreciate your concern.

---

Originally posted by [sudip](https://answers.ros.org/users/55839/sudip/) with karma: 16 on 2020-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0